# "bash:psql command not found" error

Tags: linux, postgresql, operating-system

I have installed postgressql 8.4-91 version in my Linux OS.
On going to the directory where its installed  I am able to locate psql in the directory.
I am having 2 issues.

1. on typing ./psql ,it asks for a password and doesn't accept any password.
2. On typibf psql i am getting " command not found"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second one is easy. Most secure Linux system don't include `.` (the current directory) in the path (i.e., `$PATH`).

This avoids the attack vector of providing an `ls` script in your directory that will run if someone is foolish enough to have `.` before the real location of `ls` in their path.

If you *really* want to be able to run it without the dot, the safest option is to set up an alias like:

```
alias pg='./psql'
```

and then use `pg` to run it. I would advise *against* putting `.` in your `$PATH` variable, at least on a shared machine. If you're the only one able to muck about on your machine, then you could probably do it safely.

The first you can probably get around by editing the `pg_hba.conf` file to get rid of authentication, using `alter user` (or `add user`) to set up a password then turn authentication back on.

Or you could just run *without* authentication in your development environment, as so many of us do :-)

Comment: i have not inclueded a . I just gave psql and it says command not found

Comment: @ramya, I've clarified. When I said "in the path", I meant the `$PATH` _environment variable,_ not the command line.